# calculate the days between the first and second purchase for each user

Tags: powerbi, dax, datediff

How can I calculate the time interval(days) between the first and second purchase for each user who has more than one order in Power BI? The second purchase which I want doesn't have the same order date as the first order.

for example, see this sample data:

[image: p1]

result for this example should be the same as this pic:

[image: p2]

I'm not familiar with M programming("let" and "in"). Please give me a solution that doesn't have M code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this with a measure:

```
Result_day = 
var __atleast2day = COUNTROWS(OrdTab)
var __dynam = TOPN(2, CALCULATETABLE(OrdTab), OrdTab[order_date], ASC)
var __first = maxx(__dynam, OrdTab[order_date])
var __second = minx(__dynam, OrdTab[order_date])
var __result = if(__atleast2day >1, __first - __second, 0)
return
__result
```

here sample;
[image]

Comment: your code is giving result 0 for user id 4, but we should get result as 3

Comment: why should this show 3? First order = "hi" 5/10/2003 second order ij 5/10/2003

Comment: please check result table given by WhoIsKi

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to get exact result
[image]